# How to get theme colors programatically

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to set some widget color programmatically in C# code but I cannot figure out how to get the color when they are set in my app theme and differ for day/night mode.

What I have so far:

attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <declare-styleable name="MyThemeColors">
    <attr format="color" name="colorOkay"/>
    <attr format="color" name="colorOnOkay"/>

    <attr format="color" name="colorWarning"/>
    <attr format="color" name="colorOnWarning"/>
  </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

in my themes.xml this colors are set like

```
<item name="colorWarning">@color/color_warning</item>
```

where colorWarning is defined in color.xml, different for day and nicht mode. The same is done for colorSurface and so on. This works fine.

To get the color for colorWarning in C# code I tried:

```
Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
TypedArray ta = context.Theme.ObtainStyledAttributes(Resource.Styleable.MyThemeColors);
var colorWarning = ta.GetColorStateList(Resource.Styleable.MyThemeColors_colorWarning);
ta.Recycle();
```

but colorWarnig is always null.

I also tried

```
Android.App.Application.Context.GetColor(...)
```

but this seemt to work for Android.Resource.Color.[...] colors only and not for MyAppNamespace.Resource.Color.[...] colors.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms applications can respond to system theme changes by consuming resources with the `AppThemeBinding` markup extension, and the `SetAppThemeColor` and `SetOnAppTheme<T>` extension methods.

You could use the code below to change the color which differ for day/night mode.

```
Label label = new Label();
label.SetAppThemeColor(Label.TextColorProperty, Color.Green, Color.Red);
```

For more details, you could check the MS docs with the code sample. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes#react-to-theme-changes

**Updated:**

The Dark theme is available in Android 10 (API level 29) and higher.

**1. You could change your AppTheme in `AndroidManifest.xml`.**

Change:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

To:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

And set the Theme in the MainActivity:

```
  [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
```

**2. You could change the Theme programmatically.**

Delet the `Theme = "@style/AppTheme"` in ActivityAttribute.

Create another `AppTheme2` in Styles.xml.

```
 <style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

Add the code in the `OnCreate()` method. Please note call the `SetTheme` before you load the layout.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetTheme(Resource.Style.AppTheme2);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately my app is no Xamarin.Forms application but just a usual Xamarin Android app.

Comment: I have updated my reply. Please check it.

Comment: Maybe my explanation was not clear enough. Switching between day and night mode is working good.
What I want to do is to cahnge the color of some single widgets to show whether there is some warning or error present. Therefore I defined the colors colorOkay and colorWarning. This as well as as colorError are different for day and night mode. Inside my C# code I want to set the color of a widget to eighter colorOkay, colorWarning or colorError. And this is where the problem is. I could not figure out how to do this.

Comment: In android, if you want to set the theme of dark mode, you could use the way i provided. But if you want set with your own color, you could use `Color Theming`. The native android do not provided the same thing with the Xamarin. https://material.io/develop/android/theming/color